# Parent child loop, design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say I have two classes (using C#).

Class A and B. Class A can be converted to B. Class B has a property Parent (of type B).
I have a `List<A>` of A instances which I want to convert to a `List<B>`.

The class A contains information to know which instance of B is the parent.

Let's say I loop trough my `List<A>` to convert it.

```
for(int i =  0; i < listOfA.Count;i++)
{
    listOfB.Add(ConvertToB(listOfA[i], listOfB));
}
```

The method ConvertToB creates a B instance and searches the listOfB if it's parent is already in.

So let's say our ConvertToB looks like this:

```
public B ConvertToB(A a, List<B> listOfB)
{
   B newInstanceOfB = A as B;
   B.Parent = listOfB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.ParentId);
}
```

This code will go wrong if the parent is not yet converted. F.ex if we convert listofA[1] , it's corresponding parent will be listofB[6]. Which won't be available at the time we want to convert listofA[1].

My question is how would one solve this problem in a clean object oriented way. What design pattern (GOF) can be used to tackle this problem.

**Edit:**

A is an attribute with some properties that B also has. A and B aren't related.
B can also have a list of allowed children. This `List<B>` consist of items that are part of the listofB list.

So f.ex: listofA[0] will be converted to listofB[0].
listofB[0] has a parent listofB[4] and allowed children {listofB[7], listofB[8]}

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: Can the parents have a cycle or is it strictly a tree?

Comment: It may be quite obvious, but A is inherited from B, right?

Comment: A and B aren't related actually. A is an attribute and B is some other class. With the attributes of A you can fill in most of B.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a design pattern? You can just do 2 loops. First will create the B instances and second will find&set the parents. You could even use bits of LINQ.

```
var listOfB = listOfA.Cast<B>().ToList()

foeach(var b in listOfB)
{
    b.Parent = listOfB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == b.ParentId); // this will work because there is clear inheritance so B has all properties A has
}
```

Comment: As said in a comment, you can't just cast A to B. And it's a bit more complex. See the edit part.

Comment: @user1613512 Then you must have method how to turn A into B. And B having ParentId shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from `listOfA` to `listOfB` is too complex to be merely a loop: you should encapsulate it in a method, let's say:

```
public List<B> ConvertToListOfB(List<A> listOfA)
{
   // The previous answer is quite good
}
```

If you want to add more than one `listOfA` to the same `listOfB`, you can use an extension method for class `List<B>`:

```
public static class ListOfBEx
{
    static void appendAll(this List<B> instance, List<A> listOfA) 
    {
        // almost the same implementation
    }
}
```

Encapsulation is good because after the first loop the new instances of B is in a incomplete state (missing the Parent).